# React.js not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've been trying to do the React.js getting started but when i run the example code This happens

[image: Result]

Here is the code

[image: Code]

Comment: Please post code snippets as text rather than an image. Blocks of code can be formatted using the `{}` button in the editor or [indenting each line](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code).

Comment: It's the `script` tag, not `scipt`. Moving to close as off-topic because typographical error.

Comment: Is there any console output that you can show us?

Answer (score 3):

You have a typo in script tag, you're saying `scipt`